# Construct an infinite set of functions such that $\|f_i - f_j\|_\infty \geq 1/2$ for all $i\neq j$

Tags: convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $C$ be the set of all convex functions on the unit interval bounded by $1$. Identify a subset of $C$ such that  $\|f_i - f_j\|_\infty \geq 1/2$ for all $i\neq j$.

I'm having trouble coming up with an example. My attempts so far have been to consider functions like $1/2^{nx}$ which can be far apart near $0$, but I think I need to choose an appropriate subsequence.

Comment: I have extended my answer a bit, the distance between the distinct convex functions can be arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: Wow, i find that very surprising. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f_n: [0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ as
$$
 f_n(x) = \max(1-2^n x, 0) \, .
$$

All functions $f_n$ are convex on $[0, 1]$, and for $i < j$ is
$$
 \|f_i - f_j\|_\infty \geq f_i\left(\frac {1}{2^{i+1}}\right) - f_j\left(\frac {1}{2^{i+1}}\right) = \frac 12 - 0 = \frac 12 \, .
$$

[image]

*Remark:* This construction can be generalized: For any $a > 1$ are the functions
$$
 f_n(x) = \max(1-a^n x, 0) \, .
$$
convex on $[0, 1]$ and satisfy $\|f_i - f_j\|_\infty \geq 1-1/a$ for $i \ne j$, so the mutual distance can be arbitrarily close to one.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\rho> 1$, and $a_n> 0$ be a geometric progression with ratio $\rho$. For $m\ne n$
$$\|x^{a_n}- x^{a_m}\|_{\infty}= \|t^{\frac{a_n}{a_m}}-t\|_{\infty}\ge \|t^{\rho}-t\|_{\infty}$$
so we got our sequence $(x^{a_n})_n$ ( if $\rho$ large enough).

Comment: What is $t$ in this case?

Comment: @dmh: $t^{\rho}$ means the function $t\mapsto t^{\rho}$